# Zurb Reveal 5.1.1 Shows Empty

Tags: zurb-foundation

Following the docs, I am trying to get Reveal to work. Its a pretty vanilla installation. I am loading Foundation and jQuery via jsdelivr. I can see the div I am trying to load into the modal, but it doesn't get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In order for Zurb Reveal to function properly, the javascripts must be loaded after the modal elements.

```
<a href="#" data-reveal data-reveal-id="myModal">click here</a>
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>modal content</div> 
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="foundation.min.js"></script>
```

If the `<div id="myModal">` is placed after the foundation script tag, it won't work.